# Permission denied when trying to write to a block device

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, permission-denied

I am trying to write a block device driver that reads/writes off of the network. In essence, I have modified the example [here](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/02/device-drivers-disk-on-ram-block-drivers/) for ram disks. And [Here](https://bitbucket.org/hebbo_pub/networkblockdevice) is my code. When I try to write to the block device using the command `sudo cat > /dev/rb`, I get premission denied.

```
$ sudo cat > /dev/rb
bash: /dev/rb: Permission denied
```

Can Anyone help me fix this??

I can see nothing suspicious in the kernel log.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your redirection is *not* run as root, only `cat` does.

Try the following:

```
sudo sh
# cat > /dev/rb
```

Once it works, combine into a single command line (most probably: `sudo "cat > /dev/rb"`)

Comment: I am not sure if this is the problem. The same command works when I use it against ram disk with no network connections. I will try it though.